# django url template tag relative urls

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-staticfiles

So basically I've deployed my applicaiton on vps with apache and mod wsgi. For my static files I've used {% url %} template tag like this :

```
<link href="{% static "bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Django wasn't loading static files because it was creating relative url so I fixed it by

```
<link href="/{% static "bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

But now when I go to /admin pages it's not loading static files, again because of the relative urls. How can I fix this ?

Here's my mod wsgi :

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/tshirtnation')
sys.path.append('/home/tshirtnation/tshirtnation')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tshirtnation.settings'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And my apache configuration :

```
#Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin marijus.merkevicius@gmail.com
        ServerName 5.199.166.109
        WSGIDaemonProcess ts threads=25
        WSGIProcessGroup ts
        Alias /static /home/tshirtnation/staticfiles
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/tshirtnation/index.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Dan that is simply not true. mod_wsgi is a well-supported and stable combination, recommended by the documentation. (You may be thinking of mod-python, which is not supported or recommended.)

Comment: @Marijus you should post the relevant STATIC_* values from settings.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you're right--deleting as to not confuse people

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with Django's admin static files. That's what I used. Maybe it can be helpful.

This is for Nginx:

```
location /static/admin {
    alias "/pythonenv_path/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin";
}
```